Problem with text rendering using CairoSVG
I'm using CairoSVG to convert a SVG file into a PNG image.
The position of the text seems to be off compared to the images rendered by Firefox, Safari and co. I cannot understand if the problem comes from the code, from CairoSVG or from the SVG file.
Here is the URL of the SVG file: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/Roll_pitch_yaw_mnemonic.svg
Here is the image generated using CairoSVG:

Here is the Python code I'm using:
import cairosvg
URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/Roll_pitch_yaw_mnemonic.svg"
cairosvg.svg2png(url=URL, write_to="output.png")

Did I miss something or is it a known issue?
If so, is there a better lib than CairoSVG?

It´s a different rendering behavior which can be due to a bug in the font your desktop has installed, and which is used by cairo, or in the cairo-sg itself.
Looking at the source code for this particular SVG it is clear there is an unwanted offset when there is a no-extra class tspan text mark for the words.
You can try working around this by: removing the redundant tspan markup for the text extents that need no aditional styles; (2) checking for your installed fonts that are available to cairo - the fallback sequence of fonts is: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; - I remember having poor experiences with an  Helvetica font from an outdated font-format, a lot of years back - and it would be the first to be used there. And (3): manually adjust a negative left-padding value for the misplaced elements until they fall in the right place.
update
I tried rendering it here, and it seems to be a bug in the way cairosvg will render the text-anchor:middle CSS option with different text extents inside a <text> element. I´ve edited the CSS file to read text-anchor:left, and letters had printed in the correct new place - you will also have to adjust the offsets there so they render in acceptable places.

As you, when I removed the second tspan from the <text> element, it worked fine. It's like CairoSVG doesn't like multiple tspan. But the fact that it is working with another text-anchor is bad news. I could fix this SVG manually, but I'm working on a script that will handle a lot of SVG files, so I'm looking for a more reliable solution. Thanks for your precious help.

The other path to do it is going through inkscape, calling it with os.Popen from Python -  just yesterday there was a question about it  (working - the question was about speeding it up for a large workflow).

I have it working using librsvg and its command line tool rsvg-convert. But the installation of librsvg is pretty big. I'm still looking for something simpler and lighter solution, and in Python if possible...

Regardess of getting a workaround that suits you - have you filed this as a bug against the cairosvg project? Open-source projects are usually volunteer maintained, and there is no way they can be aware of issues like this save for normal users reporting it. (Please, when doing so, remember it is volunteer work and there is no "SLA" or even any expectation it will be fixed)

Very good point. I'll create an issue on their GitHub page.
